# Tensorflow 0.12 for Windows: CIFAR 10 missing?

Tags: tensorflow

I was out on reddit and discovered that TensorFlow 0.12 is now available for Windows. Could the Windows drivers for CUDA be more performant than Linux? Maybe... worth trying since the install is dirt simple. But, I when I went to run the CIFAR10 benchmark, I got a [missing package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YBxx.png)
I'm using an anaconda virtualenv. 
I ran "pip list" and it reurns: tensorflow-gpu (0.12.0rc0) as one of the installed packages. Granted, it's an early release candidate, but the GitHub repo shows the models directory, so it should be there. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first release candidate (`0.12rc0`) doesn't include the `tensorflow.models.*` packages. We fixed that with a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/6029) that was just merged yesterday, so the next release candidate and the final release will have it. We expect to make a `0.12rc1` in the coming week. In the meantime you can get the update by building from source manually.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was going crazy for a while. I will await RC1.